# kibana&elasticsearch not connect under docker in same container

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kibana

Using the docker-compose.yml file by [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elastic-stack-get-started/current/get-started-docker.html)
(online changed version 7.9.1. to 7.9.2)

as seen below full content of docker-compose.yml;

```
version: '2.2'
services:
  es01:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.9.2
    container_name: es01
    environment:
      - node.name=es01
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es02,es03
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - data01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - elastic

  es02:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.9.2
    container_name: es02
    environment:
      - node.name=es02
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es01,es03
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - data02:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9201:9201
    networks:
      - elastic

  es03:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.9.2
    container_name: es03
    environment:
      - node.name=es03
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es01,es02
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - data03:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9202:9202
    networks:
      - elastic

  kib01:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.9.2
    container_name: kib01
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    environment:
      ELASTICSEARCH_URL: http://es01:9200
      ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: http://es01:9200
    networks:
      - elastic

volumes:
  data01:
    driver: local
  data02:
    driver: local
  data03:
    driver: local

networks:
  elastic:
    driver: bridge
```

when run docker-compose up here the logs in command window;
[image]

Comment: Elastic takes a while to startup, are you sure it's ready ?

Comment: @jujule yes, es single container runs and wells in secs fine,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that both containers are started at same time so kibana is unable to identify elasticsearch container.

### in Kibana service: Add below parameters in docker-compose.yml file

depends_on:

- es01
  environment:
- 'ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://es01:9200'
- 'XPACK_MONITORING_UI_CONTAINER_ELASTICSEARCH.ENABLED=false'

---

Instead of dict. try to use lists in env. variable